# Correct Way To Re-Use HTML Blocks and Insert Dynamic Content With Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, json, html

I have a server that collects data from 10 sources and constantly pushes JSON data to a webpage. The page uses `JSON.Parse` to get it into an object `widgetData`. The object `widgetData` has 10 properties that I want to display in the "widget".

So, the server is pushing `WidgetData1`, `WidgetData2`, etc..

For each `widgetData`, I want to create/instantiate a new widget and show the data. If `widget1` exists, then update the widget. Also, the widgets should be sorted by some text property(e.g. `widgetdata.name`).

Here's what I've done so far, but the it doesn't seem that robust:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var properties = ["MachineID", "p1","p2,"p3","p4"];
        var currentWidget;
        function CreateBlock(widgetData)
        {

            var widgetID = widgetData.MachineID.replace(/ /g,"_");
            var myWidget = document.getElementById('widget-' + widgetID);
            if (myWidget == null)
            {
                CreateCard(widgetID);
            }

            var currentDate = new Date();
            var day = currentDate.getDay();
            var month = currentDate.getMonth(); //Be careful! January is 0 not 1
            var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
            var hour = currentDate.getHours();
            var min = currentDate.getMinutes();
            var sec = currentDate.getSeconds();

            var dateString = year + "-" + ZeroPad(month+1,2) + "-" + day + " " + ZeroPad(hour,2) + ":" + ZeroPad(min,2) + ":" + ZeroPad(sec,2);

            var data;
            for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) 
            {
                data = widgetData[properties[i]];
                AddDataElement(widgetID,properties[i],data);
            }
            AddDataElement(widgetID,"Timestamp",dateString);

        }

        //create the card
        function CreateCard(cardID)
        {

            var parent 
            var newdiv
            var cardElement = document.createElement("div");
            cardElement.className = "card";
            cardElement.id = "widget-" + cardID; 
            cardElement.style = "height:500px;";
            parent=cardElement;

            newdiv = document.createElement("div");
            newdiv.className = "card-header";
            parent.appendChild(newdiv);
            //parent=newdiv;

            newdiv = document.createElement("div");
            newdiv.className = "card-body";
            newdiv.id = "cardbody";
            parent.appendChild(newdiv);
            parent=newdiv;

                newdiv = document.createElement("div");
                newdiv.className = "card-title";
                newdiv.id = "title";
                newdiv.textContent = "title";
                parent.appendChild(newdiv);

                newdiv = document.createElement("div");
                newdiv.className = "card-sub-title";
                newdiv.id = "subtitle";
                newdiv.textContent = "subtitle";
                parent.appendChild(newdiv);

                newdiv = document.createElement("div");
                parent.appendChild(newdiv);

            //last add to the parent div
            var parent = document.getElementById("Cards");
            parent.appendChild(cardElement);

        }


        //Add a data element
        function AddDataElement(machineID, title, value)
        {
            var cardElement = document.getElementById("widget-" + machineID);
            var cardElementBody = findChild("widget-" + machineID, "cardbody");
            var dataElement = findChild2(cardElementBody, title);
            if (dataElement == null)
            {
                dataElement = document.createElement("div");
                dataElement.id = title;
                dataElement.className = "card-item";
            }

            dataElement.innerText = title + ": " + value;
            cardElementBody.appendChild(dataElement);
        }


        function CreateElement(parentDivObject, childName)
        {
            var dataElement = document.createElement('DIV');
            dataElement.id = childName;
            dataElement.textContent = childName;
            parentDivObject.appendChild(dataElement);
        }

        function findChild(idOfElement, idOfChild)
        {
            let element = document.getElementById(idOfElement);
            return element.querySelector('[id=' + idOfChild + ']');
        }

        function findChild2(parentElement, idOfChild)
        {
            //let element = document.getElementById(idOfElement);
            return parentElement.querySelector('[id=' + idOfChild + ']');
        }

        function ZeroPad(num, places)
        {
            var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
            return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
        }


    </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var widgetList = new Set(); //hold list of widgets

        var start = function () {
            var inc = document.getElementById('incomming');
            var wsImpl = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
            var form = document.getElementById('sendForm');
            var input = document.getElementById('sendText');

            inc.innerHTML += "connecting to server ..<br/>";
            // create a new websocket and connect
            window.ws = new wsImpl('ws://localhost:8181/');

            //when data is comming from the server, this method is called
            //ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            //    inc.innerHTML += evt.data + '<br/>';
            //};

            ws.onmessage = function (evt)
            {
                var machineStatus = JSON.parse(evt.data);
                if (!widgetList.has(machineStatus.MachineID))
                {
                    widgetList.add(machineStatus.MachineID)
                }
                CreateBlock(machineStatus)


            }

            // when the connection is established, this method is called
            ws.onopen = function () {
                inc.innerHTML += '.. connection open<br/>';
            };
            // when the connection is closed, this method is called
            ws.onclose = function () {
                inc.innerHTML += '.. connection closed<br/>';
            }


            form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var val = input.value;
                ws.send(val);
                input.value = "";
            });

        }
        window.onload = start;
    </script>
```

What is an alternative, proper way, or best practice to accomplish this?

Comment: @benvc I will post some code

Comment: Try not to use ids for elements that you duplicate, there should be no need for the id attribute.  Your event handlers can use the element that was clicked, changed, etc to locate other elements using their relative position in the DOM.

Comment: this kind of is the right way, you can also just dump html into the DOM as a string and it will work. Many people choose to get some javascript framework involved if they need to generate lots of html from data using javascript.